# How to load test https with JMeter

Tags: https, jmeter

I have read documentation on how to use recorder, I have setup proxy on Firefox 64.0, added certificate that was generated by JMeter, but when I navigate to https://www.google.com, I am getting `Your connection is not secure` error on firefox, I disabled it in firefox settings, but it keeps throwing me that message, how can I disable it and be able to record actions in google.com?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [clear your browsing history](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-browsing-search-download-history-firefox), to be absolutely sure you can remove everything since the beginning of the time.

If the history is "valuable" you can [create a new Firefox profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) for using it solely for recording.

Another option is to "forget" about the website you're trying to record:

[image]

Once done you should be able to add the exception and proceed with the recording:

[image]

Check out [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) article for more comprehensive information and more troubleshooting tips.